# Summation e^(i/n)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to evaluate this summation $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}e^{i/n}$$ and I really don’t know how to deal with the denominator (n).So basically the formula that i should use is this one $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}r^{i-1} = \frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1}$$
I would like to change the limits of the summation by setting $j = i + 1  $.Now when $i=0$, $j=1$ and the upper limit should be $n+1$.
So this is what we get $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}e^{\frac{j-1}{n+1}}$$.Now I would be tempted to evaluate the summation of $$e^{\frac{j-1}{n+1} - 1}$$.However I don’t know how to deal with the factor $$\frac{j-1}{n+1}$$.Could someone help?Thank you in advance

Comment: $e^{i/n}=(e^{1/n})^i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can give a hint:

Take $r = e^{\frac1{n+1}}$ and substitute it in the formula that you have mentioned.

Comment: I am so stupid, thank you so much for your help :)